# Express JS - Handling POST request

Tags: express

I am having trouble interpreting the following POST request sent via Postman in Express.js: (sending `"temp": 97.7, "device": "one"`)

[image]

My POST router (in *./routes/sensors*) is a simple

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body)
});
```

and my *index.js* contains

```
var sensorsRouter = require('./routes/sensors');

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use('/sensors', sensorsRouter);
```

**Question:** When I send the above mentioned POST request, my console understands it's a POST, but the output of `req.body` is empty: {}

How can I interpret the "temp" and "device" sent as a POST request in Express.js? I found many instructions involving body-parser, but as far as I understand express.json and express.urlencoded are supposed to be used instead these days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i see your postman settings are wrong.you are sending data as `GET` data in the URL even you set request type as `POST`. Here is my `POST` setting for once of my api.

1.set header `content-type` as `application/json`
[image: setting header]

2.In the body tab select `raw` option and `json/application` from dropdown box. Then give your data as json object

[image: Body]

Comment: Thank you, that was it! It turns out you have to set the key-value pairs in the "Body" tab.

Comment: Yes ,in POST request body contains the key n values, not the url . :)